# How can i calculate all the selected files overall size?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this code where I select files using `openFileDialog`:

```
private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
            openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
            if (this.openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
                this.txtUploadFile.Text = this.openFileDialog1.FileName;
            FtpProgress.files = this.openFileDialog1.FileNames;
            if (filesn != null)
            {
                label9.Text = (FtpProgress.files.Length + filesn.Length).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                label9.Text = FtpProgress.files.Length.ToString();
            }
        }
```

In label9, I show how many files selected now I want to show in label10 the overall size of all the selected files.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the size of the file using `FileInfo` class, and get the total size using Linq:

```
var totalSize = FtpProgress.files.Sum(f => new FileInfo(f).Length);
```

This will return the total size in `bytes`.

Comment: I like the use of LinQ here